# Schemaless URLs in canonical tags

Tags: seo, url, canonical-url, relative-urls

Is it a problem to put a schemaless URL in a canonical tag?

Example: page URL is `http://example.com` while canonical tag is `<link rel="canonical" href="//example.com" />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s technically allowed:

1. RFC 6596 [allows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-3) relative URLs:

   > Specify a relative IRI (see [[RFC3986], Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2)).
2. RFC 3986 [defines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) that a protocol-relative URL is some kind of relative reference:

   > A relative reference that begins with two slash characters is termed a network-path reference […]

It can become a problem if the document is accessible from more than one scheme/protocol. So if you have a HTTP and a HTTPS version (and you don’t redirect one to the other), you end up with two different `canonical` URLs, which defeats the purpose of using `canonical`.

Also note that you don’t necessarily have control over the protocols. For example, if someone downloads your document (that contains a protocol-relative `canonical` URL) and uses it locally (`file:` scheme), the `canonical` URL wouldn’t point to your HTTP/HTTPS URL.